# Undefined offset: 1, getting this error in looping

Tags: html, laravel

I have the following code:

```
$datas = $request->all();

   if (!empty($datas)){

       for ($i=1; $i<count($datas); $i++){
           $value = [
               'questionnaire_id' => $datas[$i]->questionnaires_id,
               'question_id' => $datas[$i]->id,
               'answer' => $datas[$i]->key
           ];

           return $value;
       }
   }
```

I am getting error:

`Undefined offset: 1`

With input form:

`<input type="" name="{{$question->id}}" value="{{$key}}">`

How can I receive this value in controller?

Comment: Please properly format the questions, especially the code part.

Comment: Regardless, the issue is probably because you're initializing $i from 1. It should be `$i=0`

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that $datas is a numerical array starting at index 1 with no gaps.  That may not be the best assumption.

Based on my knowledge of `request()->all()`, it's going to return an associative array of all your user input so you wouldn't be able to access an $i key on $datas.  Just because it may have 1 element, doesn't mean that index on the array will be 1.

Perhaps you want to retrieve a specific user input, for example, if you had a checkbox named `checkbox`, you may want to use `request()->input('checkbox')` instead of `request()->all()`, but I'd still assume your array keys would start from 0 and not 1.

When all else fails, set a breakpoint and use a debugger to see the value of $datas.  If you don't have a debugger (which I highly recommend) you can use `dd($datas);` to die and dump the value.

Comment: got it..   <input type="{{$question->type}}" name="{{$question->id}}" value="{{$key}}"> how can i get the value of this input field?

Comment: In my opinion, that's a poor choice of a name for an input.  That is how you retrieve it from the request object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try initialize the variable `i = 0`.  Also make a `dd($datas)` to see what you are evaluating.

```
$datas = $request->all();

if (!empty($datas)){
   for ($i=0; $i<count($datas); $i++){
      $value = [
         'questionnaire_id' =$datas[$i]->questionnaires_id,
         'question_id' =$datas[$i]->id,
         'answer' =$datas[$i]->key
      ];

      return $value;
   }    
}
```